# Bitwise Xor optimizing and/or/not use

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

I was looking at the code for two different MD5 implementations and I seen F (a bitwise ternary operation) implemented two different ways:

in C:

```
#define f1(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) | (~(x) & (z)))
#define f2(x, y, z) ((z) ^ ((x) & ((z) ^ (y))))
```

In Pseudo:

```
f1 = (x And y) Or ((Not x) And z)
f2 = z Xor (x And (z Xor y))
```

What I can't wrap my brain around is how someone came up with f2 in the first place.  I could have come up with f1 on my own because its the logical code to write when you hear (if x then y else z) - but I couldn't have come up with f2.

To be clear - I **understand** what f2 is doing and how Xor works - I just can't understand how someone can go from f1 to f2 .. how did they know using xor in that way was equivalent?

I can't just use something because it works - I want to understand why it works.

Can someone "explain the math", so to speak?
Are there specific rules where you can use Xor to optimize And/Or/Not?

Comment: You can read it like this: start off with z and flip it if x is 1 and y is different to z

Comment: I don't know how this was originally derived, but I can give an algebraic proof for this if you're interested

Comment: @samgak: I understand what its doing - just don't understand how it was known that f2 was equivalent to f1.  RFC 1321 expresses the implementation as f1 does.

Comment: @harold:  Not sure what the proof would be - to show that the two are always equal?

Comment: @DHW yes, it's a pretty dumb proof though (you can preview it [here](http://haroldbot.nl/index.html?q=%28z+%26+~x%29+%7C+%28y+%26+x%29+%3D%3D+z+%5E+%28%28z+%5E+y%29+%26+x%29) but I'd rewrite it a bit) and I would be surprised if that's how it was originally discovered..

Comment: f1 is in disjunctive normal form (that is, OR of ANDs). Take the disjunctive normal form equivalent of XOR, and substitute to derive f2. Why would one attempt the substitution? Because allowing XOR as a basic logic operation in addition to AND, OR, NOT frequently allows evaluation of logic expressions in fewer total operators, but often at the expense of increased latency (viewing AND-NOT as a single operation, the depth of the dependency chain in f1 is two operations, but it is three operations in f2).

Comment: @Harold That proof helped.  After Googling a bit, I'm going to guess that f1 was reduced through boolean algebra and/or by using a Karnaugh Map.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks - I think that pretty much answers it.  Clearly over my head but the answer seems to be that the laws of boolean algebra were applied in order to factor it down into XORs - namely the distributive law.  Harold's proof explained it - your answer confirmed it.

Comment: Why assume that f2 was derived from f1? Why couldn't someone just come up with f2 as an implementation of the ternary bit operator in the same way they might come up with f1?

Comment: I agree that f1 is more "intuitive" in the sense that most people would naturally come up with it as a solution, but I think anyone who can see intuitively that f1 works can see intuitively that f2 works as well. If you start off with z and flip it if x is 1 and y is different to z, then the result is going to be equal to z when x is 0 and y when x is 1, which is the ternary operator.

Comment: @samgak to be honest it never occurred to me that someone would go directly into f2.   Coming back to this after two days it does seem a bit more intuitive now - Guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees and needed to step back.  But yeah - it makes sense.  If you stop thinking of it as the traditional if x then y else z .. and start thinking in terms of binary - you don't need to worry about x because it is either 1 or 0 .. so why couldn't you start with z and then just check to see if it needs to be flipped.